# NumPy array loses dimension upon assignment/copy, why?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, dimensions

I have the following code:

```
print(type(a1), a1.shape)
a2 = a1                  #.reshape(-1,1,2) this solves my problem
print(type(a2), a2.shape)
```

The output is:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> (8, 1, 2)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> (8, 2)
```

I know the (commented out) reshape solves my problem, however, I'd like to understand why a simple assignment results in losing the central dimension of the array.

Does anybody know what is going on? Why referring to the array with another name changes its dimensions?

Comment: I can't concieve of any way that the assignment `a2 = a1` would change the underlying NumPy array object. Please can you post the full code to reproduce the issue you're seeing along with the versions of any libraries that you're using? (I have seen the opencv link you've left below Ajit's answer, but I can't accurately infer exactly how this code relates to the issue in this question.)

Comment: Note the reshape at line 61 in the code: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/tutorial_code/video/optical_flow/optical_flow.py. Without that reshape, `p0` wont have the same dimensions of `good_new`, i.e. it will have lost the "central" dimension.

Comment: Yes I noticed that reshape, but there's much more going on in that code than simple assignment or copying. NumPy arrays do not lose a dimension due to assignment or via their `copy()` method, only due to specific indexing operations, explicit reshaping, reduction over an axis, etc. In your link, `good_new` is assigned to the result of indexing `p1` which is the output of `cv.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(..., p0, ...)`, so I am not surprised if `good_new` has to be reshaped to introduce an extra dimension. I don't think the premise of your question is correct, so I am not sure how it can be answered.

Comment: `good_new` has the central dimension, just print it. `p0` will lose it if you remove the `reshape` statement on the assignment. I'm also surprised about this, however, it's happening. Cheers,

Comment: Okay I think I understood: when I ran the script, `good_new` has shape `(17, 2)`. This looks to be because `p0` and `p1` both have shape `(17, 1, 2)` and `st` has shape `(17, 1)` and the script sets `good_new = p1[st==1]` (line 43). The central dimension is dropped from `p1` due to the Boolean indexing (i.e. `p1[st==1]`), and then this 2D array is assigned to the `good_new` variable. This is why `good_new` has to be reshaped before assigning back to the name `p0` (which has to be 3D). So the dimension is lost due to indexing, not assignment/copying.

Comment: Dear Alex. I completely forgot about that operation. You are right! I need more sleeping. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Dear Alex, if you make this an answer I can award you the bounty. That is, instead of a comment, make it an answer. Cheers,

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for the feedback - I've posted an answer, let me know if there's anything else I can add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [openCV script](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/tutorial_code/video/optical_flow/optical_flow.py) mentioned in the comments, the reshape to three dimensions is necessary because a dimension is being lost via Boolean indexing, and not by the assignment alone.

The names of the arrays in that script which motivated the question are `p0` and `good_new`.

Here is a breakdown of the operations in that script:

1. `p0` is a 3D array with shape `(17, 1, 2)`.
2. The line:

   ```
   p1, st, err = cv.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(old_gray, frame_gray, p0, None, **lk_params)
   ```

   creates new arrays, with array `p1` having shape `(17, 1, 2)` and array `st` having shape `(17, 1)`.
3. The assignment `good_new = p1[st==1]` creates a new array object by a Boolean indexing operation on `p1`. This is a 2D array has shape `(17, 2)`. A dimension has been lost through the indexing operation.
4. The name `p0` needs to be assigned back to the array data contained in `good_new`, but `p0` also needs to be 3D. To achieve this, the script uses `p0 = good_new.reshape(-1, 1, 2)`.

---

For completeness, it is worth summarising why the Boolean indexing operation in step (3) results in a dimension disappearing.

The Boolean array `st == 1` has shape `(17, 1)` which matches the initial dimensions of `p1`, `(17, 1, 2)`.

This means that the selection occurs in the second dimension of `p1`: the indexer array `st == 1` is determining which arrays of shape `(2,)` should be in the resulting array. The final array will be of shape `(n, 2)`, where `n` is the number of `True` values in the Boolean array.

This behaviour is detailed in the NumPy documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why your are getting this.but it should not return like this.Can you please share how your a1 has been created.

I tried like below but not able to re create it

```
a1=np.ones((8,1,2),dtype=np.uint8)
print(type(a1), a1.shape)

<class 'numpy.ndarray'> (8, 1, 2)

a2=a1

print(type(a2), a2.shape)

<class 'numpy.ndarray'> (8, 1, 2)`
```

Comment: Hi Ajit. You can see the code here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/tutorial_code/video/optical_flow/optical_flow.py. Note the last line in the code. Cheers